# Specifiy DB set type for repository when using multiple DBContexts with the same table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Multiple Databases with multiple DBContexts some tables are the same but some are not

Cut down Examples of the tables

DB1stations
Db2stations

The above tables are in the same namespace under different folders

so DbContexts then:

DB1
DB2

I have a Stations repository that takes in a Generic Type and inherits from my generic repository this class also Implements IStation Repository

StationsRepository

```
using Multi_DbContext.DbContexts.DB1Stations

public class StationsRepository<T> : GenericRepository<DB1Stations>, IStationRepository where T : class
    {
        public StationsRepository(DbContext context)
            : base (context)
        {
                
        }


    }
```

IStationRepository

```
public interface IStationRepository : IGenericRepository<DB1Stations>
    {
      //code omitted
    }
```

I have a Station Service class that creates an instance of the StationRepository

StationService

```
public StationService()
{
this._stationsRepository = new StationsRepository<TbMsStation>(_context);
}
```

GenericRepository

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{

   private DbContext _context;
   DbSet<T> _entity = null;

   public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
   {
       _context = context;
       _entity = _context.Set<T>();
   }

   // Generic Methods for Database
}
```

The issue I have is how can I pass either DB1Stations table or DB2Stations table to my stations repository, but also make sure that the Generic repository has the correct table type and so that the IStationRepository inherited IGeneric Repository also has the correct table type at runtime.

e.g

```
this._stationsRepository = new StationsRepository<fullqualifiedtypeherewithnamespace>(_context);
```

What I am asking is how to specifiy the type that the methods use dynamically as I cannot put DB1Stations as at runtime it might be passed the DB2stations type.

What I would like to do is be able to pass the fully qualified type with the name space like Multi_DbContext.DbContexts.DB1Stations so that I don't have to add multiple using statements as eventually I have more than two databases that I need to pass tables for to the stations Respository.